# Obtain list of references as it appears on the bibliography in plain text

Tags: bibliographies

How can I obtain the bibliography of an article  in plain text? (some journals require to upload this with submission)

Here is a MWE to play around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperref=true,
    natbib=true,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{einstein,
        author = {Albert Einstein},
        title = {the true about tree},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921}
    }
    @article{einstein2,
        author = {Albert Einstein the II},
        title = {the true about tree II},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    Paper\cite{einstein} Paper\cite{einstein2}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't know about compatibility with biblatex, but https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibentry.  Otherwise, copy and paste from Bibliography in PDF.

Comment: What do you suggest to copy and paste from the PDF? I tried this but non-ASCII characters were messed up.

Comment: True, non-ASCII would require special attention.